# Error "Field 'nombre' doesn't have a default value" en peticion POST Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy elaborado un ejercicio de escribir por post usando Laravel, pero siempre me marca el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si llegan los datos del request, pero al hacer ya el post hacia la base de datos lanza ese error, si cambio la propiedad de `strict: false;` en `databases.php` si me deja hacer el insert, pero no inserta nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modelo es este:

```
class Product extends Model{
  use HasFactory;
  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'nombre',
    'tipo',
    'cantidad'
];}
```

La ruta es la sigiente:

```
Route::post('/add', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create');
```

Y mi la funcion del controlador es esta:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    try{
        $jsonProduct = $request->json()->all();

        $product = new Product($jsonProduct);

        $product->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status'=>'accepted',
            'product'=>$product
        ],200);
    }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $exception){
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>'rejected',
            'message'=>$exception->errorInfo,
        ],400);
    }
}
```

Ya tambien itente otras formas de crear el insert como

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
```

Y simplemente no lo logro

Comment: Prueba con `$jsonProduct = $request->all();` en vez de `$jsonProduct = $request->json()->all();`. De todas formas te convendría hacer una validación de los datos del request antes de intentar insertar en bd

Comment: al crear el objeto producto te deja el nombre en null y como en el tu base de datos el campo nombre no le especificaste un valor por defecto, te da el error, revisa que $product este recibiendo bien la información antes del save